# iOS FGallery objective c assigning string value dynamically

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, fgallery

It is a bit complicated to explain my problem. I am using FGallery library https://github.com/gdavis/FGallery-iPhone and especially its feature to load images from URL addresses. When I hardcode the URL path it works super, but wen I pass a string variable to the class which I have created it doesn't work. I tried to debug it and it seems that everything is ok, there is a string assigned to the variable and everything, but do not show the picture. I am doing this in a loop and using ARC.

```
  -(void) loadSoftia
  {
     //======================================================================================
//THIS WORKS CORRECTLY!!!
wcSofia = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

Webcam *s1 = [[Webcam alloc]init];
s1.description=@"Sofia";
s1.location =  @"http://www.ampthillweatherstation.info/currentweather/webcamimage.jpg";
[wcSofia addObject:s1];
 //======================================================================================

NSMutableString *urlGetOthersLocations =[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@/WebHandlers/%@", @"192.168.188.204", @"BGCam.ashx"];

ServerResponse *serverResponseOthersLocations = [HelperViewController getJsonDataFromTheServer:urlGetOthersLocations];
if(serverResponseOthersLocations.data!=nil)
{
    NSDictionary *dic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:serverResponseOthersLocations.data
                                                        options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves|NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                          error:nil];
    [wcSofia removeAllObjects];

    Webcam *wc;
    int i=0;
    for (NSDictionary *locationsDic in dic){

             NSString *key;
                   for ( key in locationsDic) {

                        NSLog(@"%@ = %@", key, [locationsDic objectForKey: key]);
                    }
                    NSLog(@"%@", [locationsDic objectForKey:@"URL"]);
                    NSLog(@"%@ = %@", locationsDic, [locationsDic objectForKey: locationsDic]);

        NSString *url =[locationsDic objectForKey:@"URL"];
        //            NSLog(@"%@", url);

        NSMutableString* theString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i ",i];
        wc = [[Webcam alloc]initWithLocation: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", url] withDescription:@"description"];
        wc.location = url;//DOESNT WORK!
    wc.description =@"София";// theString;//[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",  @"aa"]; // @"София";
      wc.location    = @"http://media.borovets-bg.com/cams/channel?channel=61";//IT WORKS BECAUSE IT IS HARDCODED

        if(wcSofia!=nil)
        {
            [wcSofia addObject:wc];
            NSLog(@"%@", wc.location);   
        }
        i++;

    }
    }

  }
```

I have commented a section of the code which works and which doesn't. 
I suppose that you are not going to need the whole program, because it make requests to my local web server to get the URL addresses and descriptions, but trust me this thing works perfect.
Thank you for your help in solving that mystery.
Edit: 
Complete source Code: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/46512232/FGallery.zip

Comment: What is the property you set for Webcam.location?

Comment: Post the Webcam class code

Comment: What would massively help are a few examples of the log messages you commented out that show the failing URLs and then he hard coded replacements that do. With those I expect it will be obvious.

Comment: Hi guys, here https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/46512232/FGallery.zip is the complete source code of the app, except the web server which returns the URL addresses. If you need this I will post this code as well, but it is ASP.NET MVC project and the app gets correctly the JSON result. Thanks again for looking at my buggy code :) Hope that everyone will learn something out of this. Cheers

Comment: Please help me SOS, really if you download the project and debug it. Very easy should find what is the problem if you are good in iOS objective-c

Comment: Hello, do you need the .NET code, basically what it does is to return JSON object.